# Unable to nest JSON Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I'm having trouble nesting my objects that have a has_many through relationships via rails.

My models look like this:

```
class SessionDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :session_enrollments, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :customers, through: :session_enrollments
end

class SessionEnrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :customers   //column name is "customers_id"
 belongs_to :session_details //column name is "sessiondetails_id"
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :session_enrollments
 has_many :session_details, through: :session_enrollments
end
```

---

I'm trying to nest a json object to return an array of session details, with a sub array of customers and a subarray (one object) of session_enrollments

My controller current looks like this:

```
def return_trainers_sessions
  @trainer_requests = SessionDetail.where(trainers_id: params[:trainers_id], state:     "PENDING")

  unless (!@trainer_requests.any?)
    respond_to do |format|
    msg = {:status => "SUCCESS", :messages => "Requests Found", :requests => @trainer_requests.as_json(:includes => {:customers => {:include =>:session_enrollments}})}
     format.json  { render :json => msg } # don't do msg.to_json
  end
```

I've also tried making a class method, but am only able to get as far as nesting the customers.

I end up returning no customers or session_enrollments, so my json just looks like I never added the includes to the right hand of .as_json

Comment: Try removing the letter `s` in `:includes =>` so that it is `:include =>` .

Comment: @Trip doing so gives me a 500 error. Logs say  uninitialized constant SessionDetail::Customers.

Comment: Can you run the command in terminal instead and see what the return is?

Comment: @trip sorry the curl request is hanging up, just seeing a > on the following line

Comment: Can you throw a debugger in your `unless` statement, and then run it within the console, and then paste the exact return?

Comment: @trip god I feel so dumb. How would I do that? Rails.logger.debug ?

Comment: Make sure you have `debugger` as a gem in your Gemfile. Then add the word `debugger` as its own line right after your `unless` statement line. Then run the app where it would collide with that line. The app should freeze, and where the app was running in your terminal window, will be a prompt where you can access whatever variables would be accessible at that time and place in the code. It is there, that I want you to try and write your `msg` statement from scratch. What you'll see is the **actual** error that is causing the 500. Copy and paste that error to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch your pluralization.

```
class SessionDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :session_enrollments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :customers, through: :session_enrollments
end

# a session enrollment belongs to a single customer, and a single session detail. Similarly
# the foreign key fields should be singular, customer_id, session_detail_id
class SessionEnrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer   
  belongs_to :session_detail
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :session_enrollments
  has_many :session_details, through: :session_enrollments
end
```

Comment: Wow thanks ! I ended up making a class method but I'll try this